# Is there modded firmware available for Fujifilm Finepix S1?

Tags: video, fujifilm, hd-video

Fujifilm Finepix S1 makes really fine pix indeed, and the videos are also quite nice. One fly in the ointment, however, is that when filming HD video, one shot is limited to 24 or 15 minutes (720p60 and 1080p60 respectively).

The possible reasons for this have been covered in other questions. What I'm interested in, are there softmods around for Fujifilm cameras, like there are for Canon (I think it was), that possibly remove this limit?

(I know that this question is a better fit for Video Production SE, but I think Photography SE-s users are more familiar with the camera's ecosystem, given that this is a still camera. Also, it is relevant to other S1 users who are not necessarily interested in video.)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm convinced, but I'm willing to wait to see how the broader community views it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firmware hacks for FujiFilm cameras do not currently exist.